# How to save dynamic form fields in mongodb

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, mongodb

I am having a hard-time thinking on how to save dynamic form fields in mongodb. I already have knowledge in saving basic forms with static fields.

What I want to learn is how to save dynamic form fields (where user can add (n) of field/s)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <input type="hidden" name="count" value="1" />
    <div id="fields">
      <div class="controls" id="profs">
        <form class="input-append">
          <div id="field">
            <!--<input autocomplete="off" class="input form-control" id="field1" name="prof1" type="text" placeholder="Type something" data-items="8"/>\-->
            <div class="row" id="field1">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 form-group">
                <select class="form-control">
                  <option>Select Product</option>
                  <option>option 2</option>
                  <option>option 3</option>
                  <option>option 4</option>
                  <option>option 5</option>
                </select>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 form-group">
                <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control input" placeholder="Quantity">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 form-group">
                <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control input" placeholder="Unit Price">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 form-group">
                <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control input" placeholder="Amount">
              </div>
            </div>
            <button id="b1" class="btn add-more btn-success" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

//The script of the dynamic form

```
var next = 1;
$(".add-more").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var addto = "#field" + next;
  var addRemove = "#field" + (next);
  next = next + 1;
  var newIn = '<div class="row" id="field' + next + '"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 form-group"> <select class="form-control"><option>Select Product</option><option>option 2</option>option>option 3<option>option 5</option></select></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 form-group"> <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control input" placeholder="Quantity"></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 form-group"> <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control input" placeholder="Unit Price"></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 form-group"> <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control input" placeholder="Amount"></div></div>';
  var newInput = $(newIn);
  var removeBtn = '<button id="remove' + (next - 1) + '" class="btn btn-danger remove-me" >-</button></div><div id="field">';
  var removeButton = $(removeBtn);
  $(addto).after(newInput);
  $(addRemove).after(removeButton);
  $("#field" + next).attr('data-source', $(addto).attr('data-source'));
  $("#count").val(next);
  $('.remove-me').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length - 1);
    var fieldID = "#field" + fieldNum;
    $(this).remove();
    $(fieldID).remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you are looking how to save an array of whatever it is you can add per row? I just don't see your question is linked to node.js or mongodb. I just see some jQuery and html.